# component definition is missing display name on HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a higher order component but keep getting this eslint waring.

> component definition is missing display name

I tried adding a display name like below but it still complains.

```
import React from 'react';

const HOC = props => (WC) => {
  WC.displayName = 'test'
  return (
    <WC />
  );
}

export default HOC;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two things you need to correct.

**First:** Fix order of your functional component declaration.

**Second:** setting displayName to the component returned from HOC

```
const HOC = WC => {
  const MyComp = (props) => {
    return (
        <WC {...props} />
      );
  }
  MyComp.displayName = 'test'
  return MyComp;
}
```

Once you make the above change. You just need to use the HOC like

```
const MyCompWithHoc = HOC(CompA);
```

and render it like

```
<MyCompWithHoc propsA={'A'} {...otherPropsYouWantToPass} />
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Cannot add property displayName, object is not extensible`

Comment: MyComp.displayName = 'test' is this line necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Your HOC should take the component as the first argument instead of `props`, see the example in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging

EDIT: You can pass it props either by returning a functional component:

```
const HOC = WC => props => {
  WC.displayName = 'test'
  return (
    <WC {...props} />
  );
}
```

Or just return the wrapped component after setting the `displayName`:

```
const HOC = WC => {
  WC.displayName = 'test';
  return WC;
}
```

Comment: So how would I pass it props then.

Answer (score 0):

`HOC` is the component that's lacking a displayName property. The code you have above is changing the displayName property of `WC` which you don't want.

`HOC.displayName = 'some higher component'`

Comment: I already tried that it still complains about the WC as been the problem.