# Component definition is missing display name for forwardRef

Tags: reactjs

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.carlrippon.com/react-forwardref-typescript/) on using `React.forwardRef`, where make this component:

```js
import React from "react";

const Search = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} type="search" />;
});

export default Search;
```

However, running my app, the component causes the following error:

```
Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
```

Based [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602013/component-definition-is-missing-display-name-on-hoc), I thought I might do something like this:

```js
const Search = MySearch = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} type="search" />;
});

export default Search;
```

But this did not fix the problem either.

So then, how can I give my component a display name?

Comment: I'm not sure how the linked question led you to the attempted solution; nothing you did sets the display name.

Comment: (The linked question's answers *do* show how to set the display name, in a slightly difference context, but same thing.)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

The `Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name` message is likely coming from a tool like eslint.

It is a linting rule that exists in order to help you follow style guides and/or conventions regarding what is considered good practice when writing React code.

That particular rule in eslint is explained in further details here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md

From that page you can also find *why* it exists and what the `displayName` property on React Components is good for, namely to help when debugging, since it means that it will print your component's `displayName` property to the console instead of just `input`.

Also, from that link, you can find that when you are using function components, you can address that by setting the `displayName` property on the component. This should probably help you:

```js
import React from "react";

const Search = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} type="search" />;
});
Search.displayName = "Search";

export default Search;
```

Another option is to just disable that particular linter, using a comment with `// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name` or similar just above the declaration of your component.

That would however mean that if you were to need to debug your app, this component would simply be called `input` instead of `Search`, which might make the debugging a bit harder.

Comment: Somehow, i did read the error message, but just couldn't figure out that's what it means.

Comment: Yes, it's one of those things where you almost have to encounter it enough times to recognize the format and then remember "Oh, that looks like a linter message".

Comment: ```Search.displayName = "Search";```

This line fixed the error.

Comment: isn't it a readonly property? is there a work around for typescript?

Comment: THANK YOU. So helpful. `displayName` should be an argument in `forwardRef`.

Comment: i still get the error

Answer (score 53):

I've recently had the same issue and resolved it this way. Might not be the prettiest but could be preferred to some. Where `ComponentName` is the React name and the `ExportName` is what you will import in other places.

```
const ComponentName = (props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}></div>
  );
};
export const ExportName = forwardRef(ComponentName);
```

Comment: Are you really passing the `forwardRef` function itself as the component's ref?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question really but i can edit with correct syntax for the fowardRef

Answer (score 36):

You could use a **named function** (see `function Search`) instead of the anonymous arrow fn, like in the example below.

```
const Search = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>(function Search(props, ref) {
  return <input ref={ref} type="search" />;
});

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 17):

```
import React from "react";

const Search = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>(function Search(props, ref) {
  return <input ref={ref} type="search" />;
});

export default Search;
```

In this way, you can fix the problem. I suggest we'd better know why eslint limit the way of writting

Answer (score 15):

In addition to Larsson's response (which I think it's the way to go), if you still want to have the typings you can do something like this:

```js
import { forwardRef, ForwardRefRenderFunction } from "react";

type MyComponentProps = {
  something: string;
}

type RefProps = {
  something: string;
}

const MyComponent: ForwardRefRenderFunction<RefProps, MyComponentProps> = (props, ref) => {
  return <div>Works</div>;
}

export default forwardRef(MyComponent);
```

Comment: This answer works best out of the rest for my setup, with a bunch of ESLint rules that force named components, arrow functions, and other modern TS/React.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution the previous ones didnt work for me:

```js
import React, { forwardRef, Ref } from 'react';
import { SliderItemContainer, SliderItemContent } from '../styles/SliderItem.styles';
import { SliderItemType } from '../utils/Slider.data';

type SliderItemProps = {
  item: SliderItemType;
};

const SliderItem = ({ item }: SliderItemProps, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  return (
    <SliderItemContainer ref={ref} image={item.image}>
      <SliderItemContent>
        <h1>{item.title}</h1>
        <p>{item.description}</p>
        <button>{item.buttonText}</button>
      </SliderItemContent>
    </SliderItemContainer>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(SliderItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Usage outside of the component is also simple I just wrapped SliderItem component with motion, named it MotionSliderItem.

```js
const MotionSliderItem = motion(SliderItem);
<MotionSliderItem ..... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today. I use the DetailsList from @fluentui: Each column has an optional property `onRender` which passes the current item so that you can return a custom component to format your data. I was trying something like this: `onRender: (item: PlannerTask) => <TitleColumn item={item} />`. This gave me the error. I found two ways to fix it for me.

##### Varian 1: Give the child a name

```js
onRender: function titleColumn (item: PlannerTask) { return <TitleColumn item={item} /> }
```

##### Variant 2 (what I did eventually):

In my component file I also export a function that returns the component:

```js
export const createTitleColumn = (item: PlannerTask): JSX.Element => {
    return <TitleColumn item={item} />
}
```

Then I just pass this:

```js
onRender: createTitleColumn
```

##### Conclusion

I like this variant most because it doesn't overcomplicate things and I personally found the second option to be very readable as well.

Overall I think that the eslint error was a false positive in my case, because there's nothing wrong with my original code. However I try to avoid disabling linting or compiler errors/rules, because they don't just exist to annoy us ;)

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here using types, here is our solution with interfaces:

```
import { Ref, forwardRef } from 'react';

interface Props {
    "foo": string
}

const Input = ({ foo }: Props, ref: Ref<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    return <input foo={foo} ref={ref} type="text" />;
};

export default forwardRef(Input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on [A. Backhagen 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69302038/12163469), add a few edits to work with typescript:

```
const ComponentName = (props, ref: React.ForwardedRef< HTMLInputElement >) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}></div>
  );
};
export const ExportName = forwardRef(ComponentName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the beginning of your file:

`/* eslint-disable react/display-name */`

You could also try this:
`// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name`

Comment: This does not answer the question "How do I give my component a display name". It _will_ make the error/warning message go away, but it does not actually answer the question.